# How to set an item as by default open in shadcn ui accordion?

Tags: reactjs, accordion

I am using accordion from shadcn ui and by default all the accordion items are collapsed. I want the first item to not be collapsed by default. How to achieve this ?

I tried passing a `defaultValue` prop to the `Accordion` component but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<Accordion
          type="multiple"
          className="w-full"
          defaultValue={["tools", "style", "status", "region"]}
        ></Accordion>

//type must be "multiple", and than you can give string array as defaultValue
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete sample. You just have to assign the AccordionItem a value and then add the same value in the defaultValue. It will be opened by default.

```
<Accordion type="single" defaultValue="colors" className="w-full">
          <AccordionItem value="colors">
            <AccordionTrigger className="flex items-center justify-between pr-4">
              <span className="text-base font-[550]">Colors</span>
              {isAccordionActive ? <ChevronDownIcon /> : <ChevronUpIcon />}
            </AccordionTrigger>
            <AccordionContent>
              <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
                {sidebarData.colors.map((color, index) => (
                  <div
                    key={index}
                    className="flex flex-col gap-1 items-center justify-center"
                  >
                    <div
                      className={`!w-[1.8rem] !h-[1.8rem] rounded-full bg-[${color.code}]`}
                    ></div>
                    <span>{color.colorName}</span>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            </AccordionContent>
          </AccordionItem>
        </Accordion>
```

I found the solution [here](https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/components/accordion#expanded-by-default)

Answer (score 0):

I set the `type` to `"single"` and added `collapsible` to make it so that this item can be opened and closed, even though it's initially open by default.

```
<Accordion
  type="single"
  collapsible
  defaultValue="item-1"
  className=""
></Accordion>
```